# Accessing header attributes from model in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'd like to access the value of "accept-language" in header from model so i can determine which column should i pick.

so for now i have this in my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer  id;
    @Column(name  = "title_en")
    private String title;
     @Column(name  = "description_en")
    private String description;
    private String icon;
}
```

so i need to change the name of column according to the header language i received , for example if i received (fr) i want to receive the value of column name_fr

```
 @Column(name  = "title_fr")
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: header language i received? from the http call?

Comment: Yes , the http request i received  , I am receiving (accept-language) in header.

Comment: Not sure this is a good question if you think what JPA does rapresents , is a representation with pojo of table. you table then will have 1 to 1 with the table.

Comment: i have only two languages and basically the database was already there , so i have to go with table design , anyway do you suggest a solution for this Translation structure in spring ?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider your DB design

I would have a CategoriesInLanguage table  with three columns

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CategoriesInLanguage")
    public class CategoryInLanguage {

        private Integer  idCategory;
        @Column(name  = "title")
        private String title;
        @Column(name  = "description")
        private String description;
        @Column(name  = language")
        private String = language
   
    }

@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer  id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="idCategory")
   public List<CategoryInLanguage> getLanguages() {
       return languages;
}

}
```

something like this